# Average Nucleus size of human skeletal muscle cell

Tags: cell-biology

I’ve been struggling the last couple of days to find reliable data on the average nucleus size of a human skeletal muscle cell. If I deduce it from pictures it should be in the range of 20 micrometers long and 3 micrometers in diameter but I need reliable data and a proper source.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You may find it beneficial to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average "length" for normal human myonuclei is 11.75 µm according to the abstract for:

[Watkins, S. C., & Culien, M. J. (1988). A quantitative study of myonuclear and satellite cell nuclear size in Duchenne's muscular dystrophy, polymyositis and normal human skeletal muscle. The Anatomical Record, 222(1), 6-11.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3189887)

If you can get access to this paper it should have more information for you.

Comment: If I am correct, the myoblast are combined into myocytes. Do you think I can assume that the nuclei stay the same size?

Comment: Sorry — I messed up. The results were for myonuclei in myocytes (I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote myoblasts). Now corrected.